# How to store a user password using BASH script and access it in scripts it invokes

Tags: bash, shell, security, passwords

I have a script:

### setup.sh

```
read -s -p "Enter your password to use in script: " PASSWORD

echo -e $PASSWORD | sudo -S brew cask install junk

echo "Done Installing junk, running step 1..."
./step1.sh
```

### step1.sh

```
echo -e $PASSWORD | sudo -S some-other-command
```

Obviously the $PASSWORD will be empty in step1.sh, and usually you export a variable to use globally in other scripts it invokes:

```
export PASSWORD
```

Or you can use it as an script argument:

### setup.sh

```
read -s -p "Enter your password to use in script: " PASSWORD

echo -e $PASSWORD | sudo -S brew cask install junk

echo "Done Installing junk, running step 1..."
./step1.sh $PASSWORD
```

### step1.sh

```
echo -e $1 | sudo -S some-other-command
```

I'm assuming the first example using an export isn't a good idea from a security perspective (however, I'm not sure).  Is the second usable and secure?  Also, if not, is there a better way to do this without relying on sudo caching the password (I have a large list of scripts that take time to execute and the cache will probably timeout and I want the entire script to be unattended)?

Answer (score 1):

Don't send/use password as plaintext.

Run the first script as `sudo first.sh` and then do all privilege drop (if needed) inside the script, then call the second script normally from the first script.

Comment: Unfortunately this is for an unattended setup set of scripts so this approach will not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good idea to store the password in plain text; especially in a script file, that can potentially get shared with other users.

But if you **have to** use sudo in a non-interactive way, you can try this:

```
read -s -p "Enter your password to use in script: " PASSWORD

export SUDO_ASKPASS=`mktemp -p ~`

cat > $SUDO_ASKPASS <<SUDO_ASKPASS_EOF
#!/bin/bash
cat <<EOF
$PASSWORD
EOF
SUDO_ASKPASS_EOF

chmod 500 $SUDO_ASKPASS


sudo -A -S brew cask install junk # Notice the additional `-A`

./step1.sh

# Any more commands as required...
rm $SUDO_ASKPASS
```

Similarly, add `-A` in further `sudo` invocations, in `step1.sh`...